# Multiple fastselect refresh will allow adding on first click but does not work after selecting from list

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the multiple fastselect.  I can't seem to get the refresh to work. What I mean by that is I need to be able add a new option to the list after selecting items from the dropdown list.

If I click the add button1 the first time it works.  When I select an item from the list and then click the add button1 again to add to the list the add no longer works.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fastselect.min.css">

    <script src="js/jquery_2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fastselect.standalone.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .fstResultItem .fstSelected {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h2>Multiple Select</h2>
        <div>
            <select id="example2" class="example2" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="test1">C1</option>
                <option value="test2">C2</option>
                <option value="test3">C3</option>
                <option value="test4">C4</option>
                <option value="test5">C5</option>
                <option value="test6">C6</option>
                <option value="test7">C7</option>
                <option value="test8">C8</option>
                <option value="test9">C9</option>
            </select>

            <div>
                <button id="button1">Add Item Set 1</button>
                <button id="button2">Add Item Set 2</button>
                <button id="rebuild">Rebuild</button>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('#example2').fastselect({});

            $('#button1').click(function () {
                //alert('button1 click');
                $('#example2').append('<option value="add1">Addition 1</option>');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#example2').fastselect();
                }, 500);
            });

            $('#button2').click(function () {
                //alert('button2 click')
                $('#example2').append('<option value="add1">Addition 1</option>');
            });

            $('#rebuild').click(function () {
                alert('rebuilding');
                $('#example2').fastselect();
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial options of the `select` are copied to a hidden `div` when calling `.fastselect()` (you can check that with the developer tools). Later additions to the options are not reflected in the copy.

A possible solution would be to remove fastselect from the `select` and then add it again:

```
$('#example2').append('<option value="add1">Addition 1</option>').data('fastselect').destroy();
$('#example2').fastselect();
```

Line one adds the new select option and then destroys the fastselect instance and line two initializes it again.

Comment: Thanks very much.  That fixed the problem.